# How to test a Symfony application that depends of an API

Tags: symfony, testing

I have two Symfony projects (a back application and an API).

The back application is the graphic side, it just call API.

The API is connected to database.

I would like to test my back : currently, at each test, I make an API call to reload the database but I have the impression that I make it wrong.... and moreover it's so slow...

There is a better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I've got a project like that:
- client side: a CMS (ezPlatform, based on Symfony)
- An API build on API Platform
For some data, the symfony send request to API Platform, so database layer is only API-side.

Answer (score -1):

It depends of the test purpose. If you want to test the logic of your back app I would mock the api client of your back app and simulate responses to be sure all kind of response are well processed.

Comment: How i can mock the api client ? By example I have a list of users, i can create one or delete one, each action call the API and i would like test that all work

Comment: I tried but didn't succeeded to inject mocked service in container. You can override the service in test env with the specific test `services.yml` but I personnaly don't like this solution where you have to keep your stub in sync with your original service class.
If you're in Symfony 5.2 you can simulate specific http client responses based on request urls, methods and options : https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#testing-http-clients-and-responses